# Twitter is now blocked in Egypt , I have domain and I want to bypass throw it is there a way?

Tags: plugins, twitter, proxy, dns

Twitter is now blocked in Egypt , I have domain and I want to bypass throw it is there a way ?

Comment: If you are in Egypt, I wish you good luck and stay safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general mechanism is to set up a local proxy on your machine in Egypt. This proxy connects through secure channel to a safe host (or hosts) that route your http/dns traffic to Internet. In order to use the local proxy instead of direct connections, you have to set up your web browser.

There are essentially two alternatives for this scheme: either you use ssh client as a proxy and your domain; or you use [tor](http://www.torproject.org/) and their distributed network of proxies.

**SSH**
If your blocked machine runs linux: start a local SOCKS proxy which is now a part of a standard ssh client by running in standard terminal:
`ssh -D 12345 your_username@yourdomain_outside_Egypt.net` (where 12345 is the local port number)

Then configure firefox to use the tunnel: go to about:config and set:

- network.proxy.socks -> 127.0.0.1 (localhost doesn't work)
- network.proxy.socks_port -> 12345
- network.proxy.socks_remote_dns -> true (dns connections also use proxy)
- network.proxy.type 0

**TOR**
A safer alternative is to use onion-routing that essentially does the same thing on your machine (you've got a proxy and an encrypted connection to somewhere outside); but then the target machine changes dynamically. See e.g. [tor project](http://www.torproject.org/)

Comment: I don't get it , please elaborate more or give me a link to understand this mechanism .. note that my domain is shared host on bluehost

Comment: @ismail: I updated the description; let me know if it's clear enough now. The problem with howtos for ssh solution is that none of them is complete. If you're still lost, tell me exactly where. Good luck!

Comment: I got it working by setting network.proxy.type = 1 instead of 0 (0 means "connect directly to the internet")